# problem with style masked input plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) how can type date of right to left in input `rtl`(`start typed of day and end typed year`),(**the first typed is the day**, **the second typed is the month**, **the third typed is the year** => `third typed-year/second typed-month/first typed-day`) and format it is like: `2011/09/05`

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3XM9w/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `dir=rtl` tag directly to the input. This seems to make it work. It's a little funky when you type in the input but it works correctly. Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/3XM9w/1/

Comment: no, i want **start typed of day and end typed year**, And at the end format is:: `9999/99/99`. in this demo you is  start typed of year to day.

Comment: [I think I should be in the original file plugin changes]. how is it?

Comment: if use as: http://jsfiddle.net/3XM9w/2/ , at the end format it is not: `9999/99/99`

Comment: The plugin itself will have to be changed. I might mess around with it but it's looking to be a complex request.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's what you want to do.
I try to make it with attribute dir="rtl" 
but it's not work so maybe You can do it with change your format of mask input become this  :

```
$('.date').mask('99/99/9999');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3XM9w/4/)